# How to fix discontinuities in polyline?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, line

I have a polyline feature with all the railway tracks of a country. However, there are many discontinuities in the polyline (maybe 15 feet), that is, at several locations the polyline has a break of 15 feet. How do I make this polyline continuous such that I can run network analyst tool with accurate results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question can be found here as [Checking "connectedness'' of line shapefile in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109378/checking-connectedness-of-line-shapefile-in-arcmap)

> If you open the feature class in ArcMap and then use planarize lines
>   (give a tolerance) and the lines will be snapped and split at
>   intersection - saves a lot of work. If you don't want to split the
>   lines then consider the tool Integrate but be careful to use a very
>   small tolerance, it will snap the ends together but can make the lines
>   also snap together. Before using Integrate keep a backup as it can
>   destroy your data!

I cannot stress enough creating a backup and making sure that the tolerance is just right (you can create quite the mess if you make the disconnected points connect to something, say, within 250 feet vs. 10).